# Login cookie randomly failing on Firefox. Anyone experienced it?

Tags: asp.net, firefox, cookies

I experienced this really weird problem that is no longer reproducible at the moment.

Last Friday everyone using Firefox (at least at 3 different companies, at least one Firefox 16 and one Firefox 14) could not login to 2 of my websites. I noticed that on my Firefox the login cookie was not being created (other cookies were fine). Other websites on the same server (using very similar code) were fine.

On Monday it's fixed itself without anyone doing anything. On Tuesday I noticed the same problem again on my Firefox but it was fine again after a few minutes. I haven't been able to reproduce it since.

What could it be???

(I will solve this by using Session as well as Cookie, but I am really curious what it was)

Comment: Is the clock on your server correct? Do you have a lot of cookies so that you could have reach the size limit in the browser?

Comment: The clock! That might be it, there WAS a problem with the server time although I don't remember what day it was... But why did it affect only Firefox? Other browsers were fine

Comment: The problem is occurring here, but I can't figure out what is going on. Seriously, I successfully login at Chrome, I.E and Opera, but not at Firefox. I already checked the clock on my server and it's correct. Jon Skeet, please, where are you?!

Comment: It was the clock! @Guffa was right. The manager changed the clock back, but it keep not working. So they restarted the server and everything back to work again. Thank you!